# How do i convert an if-else statement to a switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have this program of rolling dice by 1000000 and finding the number of 1's, 2's, 3's, 4's, 5's, 6's`but i need to make a switch statement as well. Im having trouble using the scanner input

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRoll_NP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        final double NUMBER_OF_ROLLS = 1000000.0;

        int x = rand.nextInt();
        // System.out.println(x);

        int ones = 0, twos = 0, threes = 0, fours = 0, fives = 0, sixes = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_ROLLS; i = i + 1) {
            int y = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            if (y == 1) ones++;
            else if (y == 2) twos++;
            else if (y == 3) threes++;
            else if (y == 4) fours++;
            else if (y == 5) fives++;
            else if (y == 6) sixes++;
            System.out.print(y + " ");
        }
        System.out.printf("\nOnes: %.2f%%\n", 100 * ones / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS);
        System.out.printf("Twos: %.2f%%\n", 100 * twos / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS);
        System.out.printf("Threes: %.2f%%\n", 100 * threes / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS);
        System.out.printf("Fours: %.2f%%\n", 100 * fours / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS);
        System.out.printf("Fives: %.2f%%\n", 100 * fives / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS);
        System.out.printf("sixes: %.2f%%\n", 100 * sixes / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS);
    }

}
```

This i what i have so far. When i run it, nothing comes up

import java.util.Random;

public class DiceRoll_Switch {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int ones = 0, twos = 0, threes = 0, fours = 0, fives = 0, sixes = 0;
    int y = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i = i + 1)
        switch (y){
        case 1: ones++;
        break;
        case 2: twos++;
        break;
        case 3: threes++;
        break;
        case 4: fours++;
        break;
        case 5: fives++;
        break;
        case 6: sixes++;
        break;
```

Comment: What you tried so far to achieve that ?

Comment: you realize java and javascript are two totally different things, right?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? `Im having trouble using the scanner input` isn't terribly descriptive. I don't even see where in your code you're using `Scanner`. Is your question about converting to `switch` or getting user input using `Scanner`??

Comment: @tnw im asking how do i change this to a switch statement. i figured out the Scanner input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early days of programming, the `goto` statement was heavily used. It works like this:

```
if ( true )
   goto label;

System.out.println("A");

label:

System.out.println("B");
```

The above code would jump to the label, skipping printing the `A`. It's pretty simple.

Now, why did I mention this? Here's an example of an `if` statement:

```
if ( y == 1 )
  System.out.println("It is 1");
else
  System.out.println("It is not 1");
```

and here's how it works using `goto`:

```
if ( y != 1 )
   goto not_1;

// this is the 'then' part:
System.out.println("It is 1");
goto done;   // we don't want to run the 'else' part!

not_1:
// this is the 'else' part
System.out.println("It is not 1");

done:
```

If you understand this, then a switch statement won't be any trouble.
A switch statement looks like this:

```
switch (y) { 
  case 1: ones++; break;
  case 2: tows++; break;
  default: System.out.println("Unexpected number of eyes: " + y);
}
```

It compares the value of `y` with all the values after the `case`, and if it is a match, starts executing the code at that `case`. The `break` indicates that that `case` is done. The `default` 'case' gets executed when none of the `case`s is a match.

And here's how it basically works using `goto`:

```
if ( y == 1 ) goto case_1;
if ( y == 2 ) goto case_2;

// here comes the default:
default:
System.out.println("Unexpected number of eyes: " + y);
goto switch_done;

case_1:
  ones++;
  goto switch_done; // this is the 'break' statement.

case_2:
  twos++;
  goto switch_done; 

switch_done:  // end of the switch.
```

I hope this makes things a bit more clear as to how it works!

That said, you're better off using an array:

```
int eyes[] = new int[] { 0,0,0,0,0,0 };

for ( int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_ROLLS; i++ )
{
   int y = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
   eyes[y] ++;
}
```

This also makes your printing much shorter:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < eyes.length; i ++ )
   System.out.printf( (i+1) + ": %.2f%%\n", 100 * eyes[i] / NUMBER_OF_ROLLS );
```

You are basically doing the same thing for each `y`, and you should want to write as little code as possible: it is easier to maintain and to understand, and, there is less chance of bugs.

Comment: so what exactly am i doing. Im new do to coding. And honestly have no idea what im doing

Comment: No-one knows what you are doing better than you ;-) I added a (long) explanation that I hope makes some sense to you! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar. These two are pretty much doing the exact same thing:

```
int x = 2;
if(x == 1) {
    System.out.println("1");
}
else if(x == 2) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
else {
    System.out.println("None of the above");
}
```

---

```
int x = 2;
switch(x) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("None of the above");
        break;
}
```

Comment: @JordanNP Please do not add code as a comment. Edit your question and format it properly there so we can actually read it.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement consists in:

```
switch (y) {
  case 1:
    ones++;
    break;
  case 2:
    twos++;
    break;
...
}
```

and so on, where the value inside the parenthesis is the variable name you want to check, and the number after "case" is the cases it may happen. You MUST put a break after your instruction is over to tell the program it can exit the switch statement after he founds the correct one and stops executing. Otherwise, if you don't put the break; command in the "case 1" block, it'll keep executing every line until it finds a break, and both "ones" and "twos" will be added

Comment: Not quite accurate: it doesn't save compilation time, and it does not check any other cases. In your example, if `y=1` and we omit the first `break`, then these statements get executed: `ones++; twos++; break;`.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure if it executed all the instructions until it finds a break, so didn't said it. But why doesn't it saves compilation time, since its less lines to execute.

Comment: Compilation an execution are different; in fact, having `break` statements increases compilation time, but sacrifices correctness. Compilation is the process of translating the source code text into machine code; the more source code, the longer it takes. Execution is 'running' the machine code.